# Python Pandas: Making date index continuous

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following time series data:

```
           EventCount
Date
2015-06-23          1    
2015-06-25          1
2015-05-29          1
```

I need to pad the data, so the index has continuous dates, like this:

```
           EventCount
Date
2015-06-23          1
2015-06-24          0
2015-06-25          1
2015-06-26          0
2015-06-27          0
2015-06-28          0
2015-05-29          1
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `.reindex()`.

```
# your data
# ===================================
print(df)

            EventCount
Date                  
2015-06-23           1
2015-06-25           1
2015-06-29           1

# processing
# ==============================
df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='D')).fillna(0)

            EventCount
2015-06-23           1
2015-06-24           0
2015-06-25           1
2015-06-26           0
2015-06-27           0
2015-06-28           0
2015-06-29           1
```

Comment: If the Index were not sorted, one could get the minimum date with `min(df.index)` and maximum date with `max(df.index)`

Comment: I think you could even use the argument `fill_val=0` to `df.reindex`, instead of `fillna(0)`.