# How to plot a time series as a bar, instead of a line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a set of time series data (in a pandas [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974166/how-do-i-find-5-minutes-gaps-in-a-pandas-dataframe)) with gaps of data. This is expected. This time series represents sensor data and since the sensor isn't always on, there isn't always data. I have multiple sensors and thus multiple (and different) gaps in the data.

I want to show my users what times I have sensor data available. The idea is to product a horizontal bar plot with gaps in the line when data isn't available.

```
            Jan 1   Jan 1   Jan 1   Jan 1   Jan 1
            00:00   00:15   00:30   00:45   01:00
SENSOR 1    ----------------        -----       
SENSOR 2            ----------------        -----
SENSOR 3    -----------------------------
```

I can follow a [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) to get a line graph or a continuous barchart of my time series data. This is not sufficient though. How do I create a horizontal bar chart with gaps in the bar?

Comment: I'm not opposed to that, I guess, but a narrow line does not work for my users as there are much more than 3 sensors and narrow lines look very busy and are hard to follow when a sensor has many gaps in the data

Comment: That's why I said to make the lines very thick. You can specify line thickness, and as far as I know, there is no limit. Just make the lines as thick as they would be if it was a bar graph.